# What skill to use when wielding a two handed weapon in one hand?

Tags: gurps-4e, gurps

I have a barbarian which looks like they'll be strong enough to wield a two-handed axe in one hand. Up to this point I've been using Two-handed Axe skill as I've been wielding it with two hands.

**In general, do you use the one handed skill when wielding a two-handed weapon with one hand, or use the two-handed skill?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using an axe that usually requires two hands with one hand, you use the (one-handed) Axe skill (which defaults to Two-Handed Ax/Mace -3).

Same for Two-Handed Swords used one-handed (use one-handed Broadsword skill).

Details are in the box on page 220 of *GURPS Martial Arts*.

Comment: On a related note, I'm allowing the players in my GURPS game to retrain skills (and other learnable abilities) as they gain XP and spend time. I'd recommend a ratio based on how serious your game is.